# how to use javascript Regex to extract id: http://site/page?object_id=2

Tags: javascript, regex

the url: http://site/page?object_id=2
I want the number (id).

Comment: Is the given URL the URL of the current document?

Comment: current doc? I want the id in the URL.

Comment: I think Gumbo understands what you want, but how you get it can be different depending on the context. Unless we're on a "need to know" basis, and the context that the js is running in is classified...

Comment: The point is, if you've got a `Location` object such as `window.location` or any of the `a` element nodes, you can use `obj.search` to get the query string without having to use dodgy regexes that will fail if the URL is in an unexpected form. You should also consider using a proper query string parser that breaks on both `&` and the alternative `;` and does `decodeURIComponent` on the name and value, if the URL can be in any form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the URL in a string:

```
var str = "http://site/page?other_object_id=10&object_id=2";
var match = str.match(/[?&]object_id=(\d+)/);

if (match) {
  alert(match[1]); // 2
}
```

If it's the URL of the current page:

```
var match = location.search.match(/[?&]object_id=(\d+)/);

if (match) {
  alert(match[1]);
}
```

Comment: Unless the path contains an `&`.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
/\?(?:.*?&)?object_id=(\d+)/.exec(url)[1]
```

Unlike other answers, this will correctly handle `http://site/page?other_object_id=3&object_id=2`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var url = 'http://site/page?object_id=2';
var object_id = url.match(/object_id=(\d+)/)[1];
```

Comment: I would just take the $ away, your \d+ should work fine.  Also put the + inside the parentheses - `(\d+)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo.match(/(\d+)/);
```